# Order data frame columns by factor - factor order needs to be reordered

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I need to make a barplot based on two columns of a data frame. For the right order I need to reorder the factor of one column, and to reorder the rest of the data frame with it. I tried to reorder the factor, but the rest of the columns remained the same. How can I sort the whole data frame? I will show what I did with the iris data (Note that my data actually has two nominal columns)

```
> d<-iris
> head(d)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
> d$Species<-factor(d$Species, labels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor"))
> head(d)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 virginica
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2 virginica
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 virginica
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 virginica
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2 virginica
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 virginica
>
```

As you an see the `Species` columns is sorted as I wanted it, but the rest of the columns stayed. What can I do?

**EDIT**

I tried out the answers, and realize, that I did not specify my question enough:
I need to rearrange the order of the factor of the species column when I resort the data frame.
I am looking for this result in addition to the reordered data frame, so that this order will be used when plotting:

```
head(d1$Species)
[1] virginica virginica virginica virginica virginica virginica
Levels: virginica setosa versicolor
```

Until now however, the order is still not what I want:
`
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 d1 <- d[order(factor(d$Species, levels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor"))),]
 head(d1)
 #   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
 #101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
 #102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
 #103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
 #104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
 #105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
 #106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
```

#### Update

To change the `levels` of the factor `Species`, you would have to:

```
   d$Species <- factor(d$Species, levels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor"))
   d1 <- d[order(d$Species),]
  levels(d1$Species)
  #[1] "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor"
  head(d1,2)
  #    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  #101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
  #102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
```

Comment: This is almost what I want. I think I did not ask precise enough. Still, the order of the factor is not correct. The barplot will still show the order "virginica","versicolor","setosa", because this seems to depend on the factor order of `d$Species`. Do you know an answer for this, too?

Comment: @aldorado.  If you check `levels(d1$Species)#[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"`, it is still not changed.  You would have to :  `d$Species <- factor(d$Species, levels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor")); d1 <- d[order(d$Species),]; levels(d1$Species)#[1] "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor"; head(d1)`

Comment: It finally worked (after it did not work because I wrote `label` instead of `level` first) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
require(plyr)
d <- iris
arrange(d, factor(d$Species, levels = c("virginica","setosa","versicolor")))
```